# Memory Error when plotting time series in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I'm running Pandas 0.17.1 & Python 2.7.11  and I've got a pandas dataframe, shown below, with 3311 rows and 7 columns. It's fairly sparse as each column represents a sensor sampling at a diffferent rate (anywhere from 1Hz to 32Hz)

[image: dataframe]

When I go to plot it using `df.plot()` I get a long callback (below) with a few `MemoryError`s sprinkled in.

---

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-4f76bcc16520> in <module>()
----> 1 df.plot()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   3669                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   3670                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 3671                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   3672     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   3673 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2554                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2555                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 2556                  **kwds)
   2557 
   2558 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   2382         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   2383 
-> 2384     plot_obj.generate()
   2385     plot_obj.draw()
   2386     return plot_obj.result

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in generate(self)
    991 
    992         for ax in self.axes:
--> 993             self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
    994             self._post_plot_logic(ax, self.data)
    995 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _post_plot_logic_common(self, ax, data)
   1119                 ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
   1120             self._apply_axis_properties(ax.xaxis, rot=self.rot,
-> 1121                                         fontsize=self.fontsize)
   1122             self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
   1123         elif self.orientation == 'horizontal':

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _apply_axis_properties(self, axis, rot, fontsize)
   1167 
   1168     def _apply_axis_properties(self, axis, rot=None, fontsize=None):
-> 1169         labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
   1170         for label in labels:
   1171             if rot is not None:

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in get_majorticklabels(self)
   1159     def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1160         'Return a list of Text instances for the major ticklabels'
-> 1161         ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1162         labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1On]
   1163         labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2On]

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1288         'get the tick instances; grow as necessary'
   1289         if numticks is None:
-> 1290             numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
   1291         if len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:
   1292             # update the new tick label properties from the old

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in __call__(self)
    901             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    902         if self.isdynamic:
--> 903             locs = self._get_default_locs(vmin, vmax)
    904         else:  # pragma: no cover
    905             base = self.base

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _get_default_locs(self, vmin, vmax)
    882 
    883         if self.plot_obj.date_axis_info is None:
--> 884             self.plot_obj.date_axis_info = self.finder(vmin, vmax, self.freq)
    885 
    886         locator = self.plot_obj.date_axis_info

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _daily_finder(vmin, vmax, freq)
    505                     Period(ordinal=int(vmax), freq=freq))
    506     span = vmax.ordinal - vmin.ordinal + 1
--> 507     dates_ = PeriodIndex(start=vmin, end=vmax, freq=freq)
    508     # Initialize the output
    509     info = np.zeros(span,

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in __new__(cls, data, ordinal, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, **kwargs)
    181             else:
    182                 data, freq = cls._generate_range(start, end, periods,
--> 183                                                  freq, kwargs)
    184         else:
    185             ordinal, freq = cls._from_arraylike(data, freq, tz)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, fields)
    195                 raise ValueError('Can either instantiate from fields '
    196                                  'or endpoints, but not both')
--> 197             subarr, freq = _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq)
    198         elif field_count > 0:
    199             subarr, freq = _range_from_fields(freq=freq, **fields)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq, mult)
    992                              dtype=np.int64)
    993     else:
--> 994         data = np.arange(start.ordinal, end.ordinal + 1, mult, dtype=np.int64)
    995 
    996     return data, freq

MemoryError: 

Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x000000000A2304A8> (for post_execute):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc in post_execute()
    145             def post_execute():
    146                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
--> 147                     draw_all()
    148 
    149             # IPython >= 2

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_pylab_helpers.pyc in draw_all(cls, force)
    148         for f_mgr in cls.get_all_fig_managers():
    149             if force or f_mgr.canvas.figure.stale:
--> 150                 f_mgr.canvas.draw_idle()
    151 
    152 atexit.register(Gcf.destroy_all)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc in draw_idle(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2024         if not self._is_idle_drawing:
   2025             with self._idle_draw_cntx():
-> 2026                 self.draw(*args, **kwargs)
   2027 
   2028     def draw_cursor(self, event):

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
    472 
    473         try:
--> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    475         finally:
    476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1131         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1132         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1133             func(*args)
   1134 
   1135         renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2302 
   2303         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2304             a.draw(renderer)
   2305 
   2306         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1104         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1105 
-> 1106         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1107         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1108                                                                 renderer)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    947 
    948         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 949         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    950         if self._smart_bounds:
    951             # handle inverted limits

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in iter_ticks(self)
    890         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    891         """
--> 892         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    893         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    894         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in __call__(self)
    901             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    902         if self.isdynamic:
--> 903             locs = self._get_default_locs(vmin, vmax)
    904         else:  # pragma: no cover
    905             base = self.base

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _get_default_locs(self, vmin, vmax)
    882 
    883         if self.plot_obj.date_axis_info is None:
--> 884             self.plot_obj.date_axis_info = self.finder(vmin, vmax, self.freq)
    885 
    886         locator = self.plot_obj.date_axis_info

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _daily_finder(vmin, vmax, freq)
    505                     Period(ordinal=int(vmax), freq=freq))
    506     span = vmax.ordinal - vmin.ordinal + 1
--> 507     dates_ = PeriodIndex(start=vmin, end=vmax, freq=freq)
    508     # Initialize the output
    509     info = np.zeros(span,

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in __new__(cls, data, ordinal, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, **kwargs)
    181             else:
    182                 data, freq = cls._generate_range(start, end, periods,
--> 183                                                  freq, kwargs)
    184         else:
    185             ordinal, freq = cls._from_arraylike(data, freq, tz)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, fields)
    195                 raise ValueError('Can either instantiate from fields '
    196                                  'or endpoints, but not both')
--> 197             subarr, freq = _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq)
    198         elif field_count > 0:
    199             subarr, freq = _range_from_fields(freq=freq, **fields)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq, mult)
    992                              dtype=np.int64)
    993     else:
--> 994         data = np.arange(start.ordinal, end.ordinal + 1, mult, dtype=np.int64)
    995 
    996     return data, freq

MemoryError: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    335                 pass
    336             else:
--> 337                 return printer(obj)
    338             # Finally look for special method names
    339             method = _safe_get_formatter_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.pyc in <lambda>(fig)
    205 
    206     if 'png' in formats:
--> 207         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    208     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    209         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.pyc in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    115 
    116     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 117     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    118     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    119     if fmt == 'svg':

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2176                     orientation=orientation,
   2177                     dryrun=True,
-> 2178                     **kwargs)
   2179                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2180                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
    472 
    473         try:
--> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    475         finally:
    476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1131         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1132         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1133             func(*args)
   1134 
   1135         renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2302 
   2303         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2304             a.draw(renderer)
   2305 
   2306         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     60         before(artist, renderer)
---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     62         after(artist, renderer)
     63 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1104         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1105 
-> 1106         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1107         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1108                                                                 renderer)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    947 
    948         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 949         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    950         if self._smart_bounds:
    951             # handle inverted limits

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in iter_ticks(self)
    890         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    891         """
--> 892         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    893         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    894         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in __call__(self)
    901             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    902         if self.isdynamic:
--> 903             locs = self._get_default_locs(vmin, vmax)
    904         else:  # pragma: no cover
    905             base = self.base

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _get_default_locs(self, vmin, vmax)
    882 
    883         if self.plot_obj.date_axis_info is None:
--> 884             self.plot_obj.date_axis_info = self.finder(vmin, vmax, self.freq)
    885 
    886         locator = self.plot_obj.date_axis_info

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.pyc in _daily_finder(vmin, vmax, freq)
    505                     Period(ordinal=int(vmax), freq=freq))
    506     span = vmax.ordinal - vmin.ordinal + 1
--> 507     dates_ = PeriodIndex(start=vmin, end=vmax, freq=freq)
    508     # Initialize the output
    509     info = np.zeros(span,

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in __new__(cls, data, ordinal, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, **kwargs)
    181             else:
    182                 data, freq = cls._generate_range(start, end, periods,
--> 183                                                  freq, kwargs)
    184         else:
    185             ordinal, freq = cls._from_arraylike(data, freq, tz)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, fields)
    195                 raise ValueError('Can either instantiate from fields '
    196                                  'or endpoints, but not both')
--> 197             subarr, freq = _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq)
    198         elif field_count > 0:
    199             subarr, freq = _range_from_fields(freq=freq, **fields)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\period.pyc in _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq, mult)
    992                              dtype=np.int64)
    993     else:
--> 994         data = np.arange(start.ordinal, end.ordinal + 1, mult, dtype=np.int64)
    995 
    996     return data, freq

MemoryError: 

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xdcbd1d0>
```

Interestingly, if I instead use

```
import matplotlib.pyploy as plt
plt.plot(df)
```

Then I actually get a plot, though the only column that shows anything on the graph is the `bvp` column, and it strangely has a 1e10 on the x-axis (even though, as mentioned above, the data series is only 3311 long and going up to 51.718750s).

[image]

Not too sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Anaconda 4.0.4?? Best of putting pandas and python version checks as part of your code.

Comment: @mdurant good point. Fixed